# Index.html in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In my code I want to thanks to the good path, open the file Index.html in my IIS server.

I am actually using this :

```
        string path = "C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + ((LinkButton)sender).ID;
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo thefile in fiArr)
        {
            if (thefile.Name == "index.html")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path + "/index.html");
            }

        }
    }
```

I am wondering why It is working in local, but when I put my project on my server, this is not doing anything.

Comment: Check that it's actually on the C drive on the server? Have you compared the file paths?

Comment: Yes everything is absolutely fine .

Comment: I would hope it's not doing anything.  Your attempting to open whatever is set up to handle html files, from IIS (well the ASP.NET worker process), *on the server*.  I'm still trying to understand why you'd want to do such a thing.  Are you trying to fire up a web page that opens up a bunch of pages on the *client* machine?  Well, then this approach, is very, very, wrong.

Comment: No we just have some folders, with index.html So basically I display the folders on our page, and if the folder as an index . html inside, when i click on it i fire this html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

1. Your website is in different folder
2. You don't have a default application assigned to `.html` extension
3. Your web app runs under an account which cannot interact with the desktop (ie. NETWORK)

Also, instead of searching for `*` search for `index.html` in `GetFiles`.

Make sure that you understand that you are creating a new process on the machine which hosts your web site and *not* on machine that is running your browser. You want be able to navigate to a page on hosted on machine B from machine A and have a new browser window opened on machine A *from* machine B.

Comment: It is still working locally but not online. It's strange because I create folders , subfolders , files etc from the server and it works . But just when I try to open the index for a certain type of folder wich are wireframes it doesnt work

Comment: So IE NETWORK, and .html etc are set.